# Ansible Security Updates

Tags: linux, automation, ansible

I'm working on a playbook that will patch instances for security updates but I would like to get a list of what packages will be installed first.

```
  - name: list security updates
    yum:
        list: security
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
      verbosity: 4

  - name: install security updates
    yum:
        name: '*'
        security: yes
        state: latest
```

For some reason, ansible is skipping the debug task and I cant get the output.

Also, what is the linux equivalent command that is run when the "install security updates" task is run?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything there that would cause ansible to skip the `debug` task. What does the output of an `ansible-playbook` run look like?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/debug_module.html) for `debug` module:

> `verbosity` – a number that controls when the debug is run, if you set to 3 it will only run debug when -vvv or above

So with `verbosity: 4` you will see the message when you call ansible-playbook with `-vvvv` switch.

Comment: That was it - I had to run ansibe-playbook with the -vvvv flag. It actually showed verbose output for all tasks which gave me what I need but it still skipped over the debug task.